# Importing a subclass where it is under a package: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-import, subclass

`./package/test.py` is working smoothly. I am expecting `./test.py` would work smoothly just like that, but I am getting this running `./test.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    from package.subclass import Subclass
  File ".../package/subclass.py", line 1, in <module>
    from subclass import Subclass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'subclass'
```

It is able to import `class1`. When it reads the 1st line of the subclass, it gives ModuleNotFoundError. 
I have tried with `./package/__init__.py`, a empty one gives the same error as above. When I have proper imports in `./package/__init__.py`, the error becomes not being able to even find `class1` in line 1  of `__init__.py`.

File directory as below:

```
./package/class1.py
./package/class2.py
./package/subclass.py
./package/test.py
./test.py
```

Code:

```
# ./package/class1.py
class Class1():
...

# ./package/class2.py
class Class2():
...


# ./package/subclass.py
from class2 import Class2
class Subclass(Class2):
...

# ./package/test.py
from class1 import Class1
from subclass import Subclass
...

# ./test.py
from package.class1 import Class1
from package.subclass import Subclass
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting PYTHONPATH could be an option. Alternatively, given your current structure:

```
#subclass.py
from .class2 import Class2

class Subclass(Class2):
    pass

#package/test.py
from .class1 import Class1
from .subclass import Subclass

#test.py
from package.class1 import Class1
from package.subclass import Subclass
```

To run `test.py`, simply run `python test.py` or `python -m test`
To run `package/test.py`, you will have to use `python -m package.test`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an empty `__init__.py` to the directory

The `__init__.py` tells the python interpreter that the directory it is dealing with is actually a module.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Aside from proper `__init__.py`, you'll also need to use:

```py
from package.class1 import Class1
from package.subclass import Subclass
```

Note the added `package.`. Just a dot would also work, as that would be a relative import.